# Hartl RoR 3.3.2 Passing Title Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to get my title test to pass and see this error when running:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Failures:

```
1) Static pages Help page should have the h1 'Help'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/Help'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/Help"
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/Help'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/Help"
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Static pages About page should have the h1 'About Us'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/About'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/About"
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/About'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/About"
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16042 seconds
6 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18 # Static pages Help page should have the h1     'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:30 # Static pages About page should have the h1 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:35 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
```

SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

```
get "static_pages/home"

get "static_pages/help"

get "static_pages/about"
```

I've tried various answers already posted in other threads and haven't been successful. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried with lower case "help" instead?

Comment: visit '/static_pages/help' instead of visit '/static_pages/Help'...maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs should be '/static_pages/help' instead of '/static_pages/Help'.